# Track progress of long running tasks - correct approach

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'd like to track execution of some long running process and show the user completion percentage and errors (if any). If it's **one** long running process, then it's easy - you can create channels for progress (percentage) and error. What would the correct way to implement such logic when we have X long running processes?

Below is a snippet of code that works, but I don't really like how it's implemented.
I created a struct `ProgressTracker` that keeps `Url` (as a field), `Error`, `Progress`
as channels. I keep such `ProgressTracker` in a slice and once I submit all tasks I iterate via the slice of `ProgressTracker` and listen to channels for each `tracker` in `ProgressTracker`. Once the number of submitted requests == number of received responses - exit the loop.

Is it Go idiomatic solution? It would be easier to pass `ProgressTracker` to the function as a channel, but I don't know how to properly send "progress", "error" and "complete" events in such case.

The code is below, the same is available in Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/f3hXJsZR9WV

```go
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ProgressTracker struct {
    Progress chan int
    Error    chan error
    Complete chan bool
    Url      string
}

/**
This method sleeps for 1 second and sends progress (in %) in each iteration to Progress channel
For .net sites on 3rd iteration fail with error
When everything is completed, send a message to Complete channel
*/
func work(url string, tracker *ProgressTracker) {
    tracker.Url = url
    fmt.Printf("processing url %s\n", url)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i == 3 && strings.HasSuffix(url, ".net") {
            tracker.Error <- errors.New("emulating error for .net sites")
            tracker.Complete <- true
        }
        progress := 20 * i
        tracker.Progress <- progress
    }
    tracker.Complete <- true
}

func main() {
    var trackers []*ProgressTracker
    var urls = []string{"google.com", "youtube.com", "someurl.net"}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    
    wg.Add(len(urls))
    for _, url := range urls {
        tracker := &ProgressTracker{
            Progress: make(chan int),
            Error:    make(chan error),
            Complete: make(chan bool),
        }
        trackers = append(trackers, tracker)
        go func(workUrl string, progressTracker *ProgressTracker) {
            work(workUrl, progressTracker)
        }(url, tracker)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
    }()

    var processed = 0

    //iterate through all trackers and select each channel.
    //Exit from this loop when number of processed requests equals the number of trackers
    for {
        for _, t := range trackers {
            select {
            case pr := <-t.Progress:
                fmt.Printf("Url = %s, progress = %d\n", t.Url, pr)
            case err := <-t.Error:
                fmt.Printf("Url = %s, error = %s\n", t.Url, err.Error())
            case <-t.Complete:
                fmt.Printf("Url = %s is completed\n", t.Url)
                processed = processed + 1
                if processed == len(trackers) {
                    fmt.Printf("Everything is completed, exit")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:
If I add a delay to one of the tasks, then the for loop where I select all the channels will also wait for the slowest worker on each iteration.
Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/9FvDE7ZGIrP
Updated work function:

```
func work(url string, tracker *ProgressTracker) {
    tracker.Url = url
    fmt.Printf("processing url %s\n", url)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        if url == "google.com" {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i == 3 && strings.HasSuffix(url, ".net") {
            tracker.Error <- errors.New("emulating error for .net sites")
            tracker.Complete <- true
            return
        }
        progress := 20 * i
        tracker.Progress <- progress
    }
    tracker.Complete <- true
}
```

Comment: This seems idiomatic to me, but that's a matter of opinion. Are you having an issue with this code?

Comment: I did more testing and yes, this approach has issues. 
If you add a simple delay for one of the tasks (for instance if the work function in the loop add if url == "google.com" {time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)}, then the whole processing would be waiting this time and finally it fails with fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
Go playground with updated code: https://go.dev/play/p/9FvDE7ZGIrP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers! I came up with this approach and it works for my needs:

```go
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ProgressTracker struct {
    Progress  int
    Error     error
    Completed bool
    Url       string
}

/**
This method sleeps for 1 second and sends progress (in %) in each iteration to Progress channel
For .net sites on 3rd iteration fail with error
When everything is completed, send a message to Complete channel
*/
func work(url string, tracker chan ProgressTracker) {
    var internalTracker = ProgressTracker{
        Url: url,
    }
    tracker <- internalTracker
    fmt.Printf("processing url %s\n", url)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        if url == "google.com" {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i == 3 && strings.HasSuffix(url, ".net") {
            internalTracker.Error = errors.New("error for .net sites")
            internalTracker.Completed = true
            tracker <- internalTracker
            return
        }
        progress := 20 * i
        internalTracker.Progress = progress
        internalTracker.Completed = false
        tracker <- internalTracker
    }
    internalTracker.Completed = true
    tracker <- internalTracker
}

func main() {
    var urls = []string{"google.com", "youtube.com", "someurl.net"}
    var tracker = make(chan ProgressTracker, len(urls))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(urls))

    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(workUrl string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            work(workUrl, tracker)
        }(url)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(tracker)
        fmt.Printf("After wg wait")
    }()

    var completed = 0

    for completed < len(urls) {
        select {
        case t := <-tracker:
            if t.Completed {
                fmt.Printf("Processing for %s is completed!\n", t.Url)
                completed = completed + 1
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Processing for %s is in progress: %d\n", t.Url, t.Progress)
            }
            if t.Error != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Url %s has errors %s\n", t.Url, t.Error)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here I pass `ProgressTracker` as a channel (fields in `ProgressTracker` are declared as simple fields, not channels) and on each event from work function return a complete state of what's is going on (if progress increased - set new value and return the a structure
to channel, if error happened - set the error and return the structure, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You're deadlocking because you're continuing to `select` against trackers that have finished with no default. Your inner `for` loop iterates *all* trackers every time, which includes trackers that are done and are never going to send another message. The easiest way out of this is an empty `default`, which would also make these behave better in real life where they don't all go at the same pace, but it does turn this into a tight loop which will consume more CPU.

Your `WaitGroup` doesn't do anything at all; you're calling `Wait` in a goroutine but doing nothing when it returns, and you never call `Done` in the goroutines it's tracking, so it will never return. Instead, you're separately tracking the number of `Complete` messages you get and using that instead of the WaitGroup; it's unclear why this is implemented this way.

Fixing both resolves the stated issue: https://go.dev/play/p/do0g9jrX0mY

However, that's probably not the right approach. It's impossible to say with a contrived example what the right approach would be; if the example is all it needs to do, you don't need any of the logic, you could put your print statements in the workers and just use a waitgroup and no channels and be done with it. Assuming you're actually doing something with the results, you probably want a single `Completed` channel and a single `Error` channel shared by all the workers, and possibly a different mechanism altogether for tracking progress, like an atomic int/float you can just read from when you want to know the current progress. Then you don't need the nested looping stuff, you just have one loop with one `select` to read messages from the shared channels. It all depends on the context in which this code is intended to be used.